# How to reference *.d.ts in vscode globally

Tags: typescript, reference, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript-typings

To enable intellisense in vscode for frameworks such as jasmine, we need to reference the typing file explicitly at the top of every typescript file like below:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
```

Is there a way to globally reference all the typing files in vscode so we don't need to reference them in each typescript file?

Comment: They generally get picked up automatically unless you have specified the `types` array in tsconfig. If you have, add jasmine to it. In fact, excluding types is what is hard

Comment: I assume you were writing test suites. To enable ts, you have to create a  `tsconfig.json` under your test files directory. In most cases, there is something wrong with `tsconfig.json` when intellisense is not working.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `tsconfig.json`, typings from `node_modules/@types` should be picked up automatically. You can make sure you TS file is part of your `tsconfig.json` by running the `TypeScript: Go to Project Configuration` command in VSCode

If you have a `tsconfig.json` but still are not seeing the jasmine typings, try updating your `tsconfig.json` to explicitly include the jasmine types:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jasmine"
        ]
    }
}
```

If that still isn't working, please [file a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

Comment: Note this assumes you are using TypeScript 2.2+